# How do I count columns on a custom WPDB query?

Tags: wpdb, columns, count

How would I count the columns of a custom `WPDB` query?

This does work although I need a different kind of output:

```
$sql_assoc = "SELECT * FROM test";
$num_cols  = count((array) current($sql_assoc));

echo $num_cols;

OUTPUT: 
47
```

But what I would want is every `column`+the total as output, like so:

`4712345678910111213141516171819202122232425262728293031323334353637383940414243444546`

Usually you'd accomplish this by doing the following but of course this won't work in wordpress or at least I have no idea how to use `field_count` in wordpress since outputting query results of a custom `WPDB` goes differently like so in PHP:

```
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM test"
 if($result = $mysqli->query($sql))
      {
        $numcol = $mysqli->field_count;
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible.

I instead created functions to execute count queries.

Answer (score 2):

Under straight mysql core functions you would use mysql_num_fields, but through $wpdb (wordpress database object), I found the following worked for me.

```
    $result = $wpdb->get_results('DESCRIBE '.$table,ARRAY_A);
    $columns = array();
    foreach($result as $row) {
        $columns[] = $row['Field'];
    }
    $num_fields = count($columns);
```